# Awesome CV - Title Misalignment - Format Problem

Tags: overleaf, awesome-cv, format

I was working on a copy of my resume on overleaf. The original resume has no problem with the formatting problem. However, when I make a copy of it in overleaf, the copy file would always have this format problem where the title shifts some to the right.

Is this an inherent problem with the copy mechanic in Overleaf?
How do I fix this?

```
\cvsection{Projects}

\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
    {} % Empty position
    {Position } % Project
    {} % Empty location
    {} % Empty date
    {
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) bullet points
        \item {Blank.
}
        \item {Blank   
}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------   

\cventry
    {} % Empty position
    {Position 2} % Project
    {} % Empty location
    {} % Empty date
    {
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) bullet points
        \item {blank}
            \item {blank}
        \item {blank}
        \item {blank}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
```

[image: The encircled part]

Comment: you should provide an example that shows the problem, it's very hard to debug a fragment. note `\item {Blank. }`  is wrong and could generate a spurious white line in the output, there should be no braces. But possibly your issue is that your existing project will use whatever texlive was current when you set it up, but your new one will use texlive 2023 (I think) in any case check the left side bar or log file which texlive version is being used

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr. Carlisle. The texlive version was 2016 for my original file. I guess  the gap is pretty huge between 2016 and 2023.